# What do "strict" or "loose" comparisons mean for PhoneNumberUtils.compare?

Tags: android

[`PhoneNumberUtils.compare`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#compare(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) with the signature `(Context context, String a, String b)` lets you compare two phone numbers to see if they are equal. The documentation says:

> Checks a resource to determine whether to use a strict or loose comparison algorithm.

What does this mean? How is it checking a resource to determine which algorithm to use, and how do the algorithms differ?

Comment: As far as the resource, it calls `getResources().getBoolean()` on the `Context` to retrieve a `bool` that would be set by the carrier; namely `config_use_strict_phone_number_comparation`. As for the algorithms, they're rather involved, and tedious. However, the main difference is that the loose algorithm is basically just doing blind comparisons of the character data, right to left, which usually suffices for caller ID on domestic numbers. The strict algorithm takes into account all sorts of wacky minutiae for the cluster that is international telephony.

Comment: If you like, you can have a look at the source. The loose algorithm: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.java#475. And the strict: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.java#593.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks, sounds like an answer post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is it checking a resource to determine which algorithm to use

It calls `getResources().getBoolean()` on the `Context` parameter to retrieve a `bool` resource that will have been set by the carrier; namely:

```
com.android.internal.R.bool.config_use_strict_phone_number_comparation
```

Just to note, the `compare(String a, String b)` method automatically uses the loose method.

> how do the algorithms differ?

Both are rather involved, and tedious, but the main difference is that the loose algorithm is basically doing blind character comparisons, right to left, accounting pretty much only for formatting differences. This is usually more than sufficient for domestic calls.

The strict algorithm, however, takes into account all sorts of minute rules for international numbers and their varying acceptable differences; e.g., as commented in the source, "090-1234-1234 must not be equal to 90-1234-1234 in Japan".

These algorithms are (currently) in the methods named `compareLoosely()` and `compareStrictly()` in [the source code for `PhoneNumberUtils`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.java). I've not linked directly to the line numbers, as that's the master branch, and they're sure to change eventually.

Essentially, if you're relatively certain that you'll be dealing only with domestic numbers, the loose method is probably fine. If you're going to be handling international numbers, use the strict method.

Comment: In my case, since I'm compiling the app with internal methods enabled, do you know if I could call compareStrictly() directly, or are there any downsides for that? Like, if the boolean returns false (in my case, it just throws NotFoundException, so wtf), is it a problem that I'm still calling the strict method? I'm trying to always use it. But I don't know if that depends on the carrier or if I can just force it.

Comment: From what I just tried, it seems my carrier has the boolean on false or something. Using 1-650-555-1234 / 650-555-1234, and 090-1234-1234 / 90-1234-1234, `compare(Context,String,String)` and `compareLoosely(String,String)` return true for both, which is wrong. Then `compareStrictly(String,String)` gives true for the 1st and false for the 2nd, which is correct, acording with the documentation for `compareStrictly(String,String,boolean)`. Seems to work just fine, even though the normal methods wouldn't use the strict version by default. Just don't know if there are downsides of forcing it.